# Are include guards redundant if variables and functions are declared as inline in header files?

Tags: c++, inline, one-definition-rule

Suppose that I want to define a bunch of mathematical constants in a header file called `Constants.h`.

Constants by default have internal linkage, so by inlining them, we're defining them with external linkage (as well as legally breaking the one definition rule).

Include guards exist to enforce ODR by not allowing the same definitions to be preprocessed multiples times. This brings me to my question, are include guards redundant for inlined constant variables or inlined functions?

EXAMPLE

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

namespace constants
{
    inline const double pi { 3.14159265358979323846 };
    inline const double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
    inline const double sqrt_2 { 1.41421356237309504880 };
}

#endif
```

Comment: Include guards prevent multiple definitions of the same symbol in a single translation unit. Your example with inline variables [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/ymCKDS).

Comment: @IlCapitano Wait, so multiple definitions of inline are not allowed in the same translation unit, but allowed across different translation units?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm Yes. The same is also true for `inline` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Include guards exist for more than ODR purposes. They also stop multiple inclusions of the same header (possibly transitively) bloating your compilation unit and slowing down compilation of your project - this matters *a lot* when you have 500.000+ lines of code in 40.000+ files. For example.

Comment: This doesn't address the question being asked. Not even remotely.